# Is there a difference between embedded and nested loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

Are embedded and nested loops just synonyms? An example of each would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think both are same, coz even google will suggest nested loops if type embedded loops :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an "embedded" loop.  A nested loop is a loop within a loop.  For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < length; j++) // <----- nested loop
    {
      //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Embedded" and "nested" both imply "something inside something else".

Loop inside a loop.

I'm not sure what other meaning "embedded loop" would imply.

Answer (score 0):

nested loops is loops inside a loop right? sure embedded loops is also a nested loop. samething which can be used to tell the below snipped:

```
for( var i=0; i<someValue; i++){ // parent loop
  for(var j=0; j<someValue; j++){ // loop within a loop
     //some code
  }
}
```